# Bundling choice dependencies before pushing distro to machine for further build

Tags: node.js, module, package, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a yarn workspace directory structure like so:

```
monorepo/
└── packages/
    ├── core/
    │   └── package.json
    └── distro/
        └── package.json
```

*Distro* uses code from *core* by requiring *core* through workspaces (which I believe uses `npm link` under the hood). Neither core or distro will ever be published; but *distro* does need to be 'built' on different machines (some of its' dependencies use make commands to build for correct architectures). Core is pretty agnostic.

In a situation where I would like to push *distro* to (say) an IOT machine for building, the IOT machine no longer has access to `packages/core` as it is a yarn workspace. I could push the whole monorepo, but then I'm forcing the machine to **1)** store some code that won't be used (there are other packages in the monorepo) and **2)** forcing the machine to use yarn over npm.

Similarly, I can't build the *distro* locally and then push because (as mentioned earlier) certain external dependencies do require building for specific architectures.

Aside from the more general question of "how would you go about managing this?", I guess a more direct question would be; is there a build system that would allow me to bundle some local dependencies together into a build (*distro* + *core*) while being flexible enough to install the external dependencies as they are needed from the IOT machine? Interested to know how would others go about managing this?

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's not the answer you are looking for, but you really should not tear apart a single workspace out of your repository for a standalone build.

When a monorepo is managed by Yarn Workspaces, every package (aka "workspace") is not self-contained anymore. For example, you will have single `yarn.lock` on the top level of the repository. When you are building a project without the surrounding context, this lock file is not available to the build tool and the dependency tree is recreated from `package.json`, potentially resulting in different versions of dependencies on every build.

---

*Update following the discussion in comments to make it easier to follow for future readers -*

Yarn Workspaces is probably the best you can get today to manage a monorepo with a single tool. However, it mostly assumes that you are building a single system from smaller and more manageable pieces ("workspaces"). This is typically true for cloud-deployed systems, where you always deploy it as a whole, but may not fully suit your needs for a distributed system, where you version and release your pieces ("packages") separately. The combination of NPM+Lerna may fit better in this use case.

Unfortunately, I don't have enough practical experience with Lerna to give a good example. I would explore something along these lines - make sure every package has own lock file (which means no Yarn), build `core` and publish it as timestamped version to some internal npm repo (GPR, Artifactory, verdaccio etc), then pull `distro` to the target machine, upgrade `core` dependency to the published version, do `npm install` and run the tests.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment. But this feels like a monorepo vs single repo argument. Without throwing the book; there are many reasons why developers choose a monorepo structure and I think they are well documented. Unless you’re suggesting that yarn workspaces is particularly bad for managing monorepos?

Comment: Absolutely not. Yarn Workspaces is probably the best you can get today with a single tool, However, it mostly assumes that you are building a single system from smaller and more manageable pieces ("workspaces"). This is typically true for cloud-deployed systems, where you always deploy it as a whole, but may not fully suit your needs for a distributed system, where you version and release your pieces ("packages") separately - IMHO, the combination of NPM+Lerna may fit better in this use case.

Comment: That's why I included lerna in the question's tags; as I had a hunch that it might fit. But could you give an example of how you would achieve such a structure with lerna? This would make a better answer I believe.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough practical experience with Lerna to give a good example. I would explore something along these lines - make sure every package has own lock file (which means no Yarn), build `core` and publish it as timestamped version to some internal npm repo (GPR, Artifactory, verdaccio etc), then pull `distro` to the target machine, upgrade `core` dependency to the published version, do `npm install` and run the tests.